# In python websocket client, why should the ping_interval be greater than ping_timeout

Tags: python, websocket, ping

I don't understand why ping interval should be greater than ping timeout. In the websocket code found [here](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/blob/master/websocket/_app.py), it defines

> ping_interval: automatically send "ping" command every specified period(second) if set to 0, not send automatically.
>
> ping_timeout: timeout(second) if the pong message is not received.

but the code says:

```
if ping_timeout and ping_interval and ping_interval <= ping_timeout:
    raise WebSocketException("Ensure ping_interval > ping_timeout")
```

If `ping_interval` is greater than `ping_timeout`, wouldn't this cause the connection to timeout permanently?

Assume that `ping_interval` is greater than `ping_timeout`, then as long as I get a response from the server within `ping_timeout`, it's fine. However, why is it **necessary** for `ping_interval` to be greater than `ping_timeout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect it's because the "ping"s are not expected to be sent out before the previous one got a reply or timed out.

For example you send a ping at time t, and wait for `t+ping_timeout` for a reply. If `ping_interval <= ping_timeout`, you'd have to send out a second ping at `t+ping_interval`, before `t+ping_timeout`, and manage many pings in parallel.

Comment: I think you're right. After reading the code more carefully, that seems to be the case.